# How to write a C++ constructor with same signature as copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I am writing a class that can optionally have a reference to its parent. In other words the class looks something like this:

```cpp
class X {
    const X* parent;
public:
    // (1) Default constructor with no parent 
    X() : parent(nullptr) {}
    // (2) Constructor that accepts a parent
    X(const X& parent) : parent(&parent) {}
};
```

The problem is that constructor 2 is the copy constructor, but it's not working as a copy constructor.

Obviously I could just have constructor 2 take a pointer. Another solution could be to make a static method to construct a new `X` and set its `parent` member.

Every solution has annoying drawbacks:

- Possibly constructor does something with parent so if I passed it as a pointer I'd have to handle the `nullptr` case at runtime.
- If I create a static function to initialize an `X` with a parent, then I have to make `X` copyable or moveable.

Is there a standard idiom or pattern for dealing with this situation?

Comment: You could use a tag. `struct with_parent {};` `X(with_parent, const X& p) : parent(&p) {}` - Btw, should't the member variable be `const X*`?

Comment: Yes it should be `const`, thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with taking a pointer as input? Since you are storing a pointer anyway. You only need 1 constructor:  `class X { const X* parent; public: X(const X* parent = nullptr) : parent(parent) {} };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tag dispatching to handle this by creating a tag type that you using to signal you want the construct with pointer to parent behavior instead of copy construction.  That would look like

```
struct parent_reference {};

class X {
    const X* parent;
public:
    // (1) Default constructor with no parent 
    X() : parent(nullptr) {}
    
    // (2) Constructor that accepts a parent
    X(parent_reference, const X& parent) : parent(&parent) {}
            
    // (3) Copy Constructor
    X(const X& that) = default;
};

X a;                       // default
X b(a);                    // copy
X c(parent_reference{}, b) // b is now the parent of c
```

Comment: Okay, perfect, I think this is the idiom I was looking for!

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Glad to help.